# Extract objects using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, instance, information-extraction

While using reflection is it possible to extract objects or variables no matter `static` or not. for example

```
class MainApp
{
    static void Main()
    {            
        ConcretePrototype1 p1 = new ConcretePrototype1("I");
        ConcretePrototype1 c1 = (ConcretePrototype1)p1.Clone();
        Console.WriteLine("Cloned: {0}", c1.Id);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to extract

1. `p1` and `c1` both so i can check its type
2. the method call from p1.clone()

so far this is what i have done with a resulting array with 0 elements

I am loading Assembly from other file

```
var name = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(open.FileName);
name.GetType("PrototypePattern.MainApp").GetFields(BindingFlags.GetField|BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Comment: it is not in same assembly. I am loading assembly from file.

Comment: You cannot access local variables with Reflection.

Comment: @HansPassant what approaches can be used to extract if we have to? without going for complex ways using roslyn by microsoft etc

Comment: You are missing the "can't do it" message.  A debugger has half a shot at it, none when the code runs in Release mode.  Local variables are heavily optimized by the jitter, storing them in cpu registers is a very important speed improvement.  That and programs cannot debug themselves.  Roslyn is no help, that's the compiler view of the code, not the runtime view.  Perhaps the most important detail you miss is that local variables live for a very short time.  A hand-full of microseconds at best, while the method runs.  You only have a hope of seeing their values when you can stop the code.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with information extraction.  You should remove the tag.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction

Comment: @HansPassant well I agree. but still may be i am missing something. but is source code parsing my last hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract all fields (private/public/static/non-static) use:

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

**Edit**

You cannot get variables and methods calls *inside* methods using simple reflection. This requires actually reading the bytecodes of the method and analyzing it - not an easy task.

If you're still keen on it, I suggest checking out libraries such as [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) or [CCI](http://cciast.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I do not want to clone i want to reterive Object `p1` and `c1` and call of p1.clone()

Comment: I am working on design pattern recovery from assemblies so i need to verify the relations that client makes an instance of a class for ex class named X and we have to see that someone makes instance of class `X ins = new X()` and call a method from it something this type to make a small oveview